# Enable Internet-based features in Windows 10 Search

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-registry, search, windows-search

For some reason, internet-based features are not appearing for me in the Windows 10 search box (such as web searches, image recognition searches, etc., though email and contact search does work.). When I open the search interface, I see a list of Top Apps and a list of Recent activities, as well as various category options at the top. I do not see an option to do a reverse image search at the bottom, nor do I see any current events related content.

I would like these features enabled. I have tried ending and restarting the `SearchUI.exe` process in Task Manager, signing out of Cortana, allowing access to all data in privacy settings, and setting the registry values to the opposite of [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/224159/how-to-disable-bing-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/) to disable these features.

These features were working for me a few weeks ago when I first set up the PC as new. Perhaps there is some other setting I am missing? Maybe I need to change something in my Microsoft account? Might it have to do with me installing the new Microsoft Edge and enabling the side-by-side experience with Microsoft Edge Legacy?

I have attached a screenshot of my experience (file names edited out).[image: My search experience]
Notice the missing features compared to [this image](https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?quality=85&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fos%2Fcreatr-uploaded-images%2F2020-04%2F6f9e2e10-8a47-11ea-87ff-0a1a400862f7&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=40cce5ec063b3ffab6cd6bd94e1fef954a263595).

Output of `winver`
`Microsoft Windows Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.815)`

Output of `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search`

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
    InstalledWin32AppsRevision    REG_SZ    {BA70C894-4BDB-4E21-A973-4E39D1A3FF86}
    InstalledPackagedAppsRevision    REG_SZ    {EE2C6D1B-BDE6-4359-8F1C-C5E952DC96AC}
    ReplaceCortanaCheckRefreshed    REG_DWORD    0x1
    CortanaIsReplaceable    REG_DWORD    0x0
    CortanaIsReplaced    REG_DWORD    0x0
    DeviceHistoryEnabled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    CortanaCapabilityFlags    REG_DWORD    0x2e80
    CortanaCapabilities    REG_SZ    CortanaExperience,Microphone,PhoneCall,SpeechLanguage,InputPersonalization
    CortanaMUID    REG_SZ    MUID=80427004f591463c995c4ff9a7ad8056
    CortanaInAmbientMode    REG_DWORD    0x0
    CortanaStateLastRun    REG_BINARY    B965A65E00000000
    NamespaceSettingsRevision    REG_SZ    {8D011CCE-1C91-4D38-8A48-96E6EEDBBF0E}
    AnyAboveLockAppsActive    REG_DWORD    0x0
    IsWindowsHelloActive    REG_DWORD    0x0
    IsAssignedAccess    REG_DWORD    0x0
    HasAboveLockTips    REG_DWORD    0x1
    CortanaServiceTarget    REG_SZ    cortana.bing.com
    CortanaUserAuthority    REG_SZ
    CortanaUserId    REG_SZ
    IsMicrophoneAvailable    REG_DWORD    0x1
    SearchboxTaskbarMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\CortanaAppOverride
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Flighting
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\InkReminder
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\JumplistData
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Launch
```

Comment: @Furty I have added more details, thank you!

Comment: mmh thanks, what do you see when you run the command "winver"? Is it a PC at work?

Comment: It's a personal computer. `Microsoft Windows Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.815)` @Furty

Comment: Update: I was able to mostly solve my problem by running [this Windows search reset script](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/100295). However, Cortana integration remains broken (meaning I can't type in search and be redirected to Cortana). Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mostly solve my problem by running [this Windows Search reset script](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/100295). However, Cortana integration does not function as demonstrated [here](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-insider/131218-no-keyboard-input-cortana-1903-a.html#post1619271), however, it may be that it is no longer possible to type commands to Cortana. (Still, I would like this feature back if anyone knows how.)